# Are there any mass-preserving raster projection algorithms?

Tags: coordinate-system, interpolation, algorithm, gis-principle

Raster maps (e.g. as a GeoTIFF) can be reprojected using tools like gdalwarp. While these tools do a decent job to project images, they are not truly mass-preserving, i.e. the total sum of the values (multiplied by grid cell size) is not exactly the same before/after reprojection.

Note that this problem does not assume a major change in raster resolution, just a different reference system.

While I understand that total mass can be adjusted by multiplication the whole grid with some factor (which is easily computed as the ratio of input and output maps), I'm looking for a method that preserve mass automatically, and also locally (i.e. all mass within a source pixel is distributed among neighbouring destination pixels). Do these algorithms exist?

I could develop my own (based on intersections of vectorised versions of input and output grids), but I'm wondering if they are already out there.